# Combine n number of Text objects

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In `SwiftUI`, you can combine `Text` objects like so:

```
var body: some View {
    Text("You can") + Text(" add lots of objects that wrap normally")
}
```

This gives the benefit of having multiple Text objects that act as one, meaning they are on the same line and wrap appropriately.

What I can't figure out is how to combine n number of `Text` objects, based on an array or really any way to increment.

I've tried `ForEach` like so,

```
var texts = ["You can", " add lots of objects that wrap normally"]
var body: some View {
    ForEach(texts.identified(by: \.self)) {
        Text($0)
    }
}
```

But that looks like this

[image]

when I want it to look like this

[image: Manual Implementation]

Could anyone show me how this is done?

Use case: Styling part of a Text object and not the other parts. Like what is possible with `NSMutableAttributedString`

Comment: In order to style part of the Text object and not all of it, such as to have half of it blue and and the other half red

Comment: I feel like this question would solve that one too, and I do believe this has a use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be describing something like this:

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    let strings = ["manny ", "moe", " jack"]
    var texts = strings.map{Text($0)}
    texts[1] = texts[1].underline() // illustrating your use case
    return texts[1...].reduce(texts[0], +)
}
```

However, I think it would be better to wait until attributed strings arrive.